# XQuartz: xterm command slow since last update

Tags: terminal, x11, xquartz

I often use the following command to get a new terminal on XQuartz.

```
xterm -sh 1.01 -u8 -fa 12 -fg LightBlue -bg black &
```

However, since the last update of XQuartz, it takes about 1 min for the new terminal to open, whereas a simple xterm command without any options is immediate.

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The last update of XQuartz ( 2.7.11_rc2 (xorg-server 1.18.4) ) seems to have corrected the problem.